# Inheriting from one base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I've been using the following bit of code in a cookie cutter fashion, across dozens of classes

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

All of these classes implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. To silence my DRY alarms, lately I've been refactoring these classes to inherit my base class `PropertyNotifier` whose only purpose is to provide `NotifyPropertyChanged` for classes that inherit from it -- which are the dozens of `ViewModel` classes in my huge project.

It feels lazy and a bit dirty. Am I hurting performance or breaking good design practices? I figure if change notification was supposed to be this easy, there would be a base class already in the WPF framework that does what my `PropertyNotifier` class does.

Note that, for a lot of reasons, I've been having performance issues with my UI responsiveness -- mostly due to a large number of controls. So I'm looking to trim the fat wherever I can. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common base class to have in WPF or Silverlight development and won't noticeably affect performance. The only problem I have with `PropertyNotifier` as a base class results from being restricted to single inheritance but that tends to be a rare issue with the type of class you'll need it for.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's very common practice. For a large scale application it becomes necessary to have this kind of base class. We had also created a `BaseViewModel` for the same purpose; we also implemented a lot of common code(across ViewModels) in this base class like logging, displaying error messages, initializing WCF proxy objects etc.

Comment: I knew people were using them, but I ended up with a similar BaseViewModel sort of by accident. It's really nice to have a base VM class to put in between WPF and Entity Framework. It saves me a ton of work. I use mine mostly to generate an ObservableCollection<T> from an EF ObjectSet, and keep track of adding/removing new Ts, and a SelectedItem T in addition to the property notification the things you pointed out like initializing, proxy objects, etc

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation is the **Model** class of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It does exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for posting this jbe, that looks like a great framework. It seems as though I've reinvented the wheel!